# Entity framework - Three foreign keys for same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Table "Projeto" with 3 foreing keys to the same table "Usuario".

When i try to insert a new "Projeto", i got the error: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

This is my insert/save code

```
    Usuario usuarioLogado = UsuarioService.GetById(ControlesDeAcesso.IdUsuarioLogado());

    Projeto projeto = new Projeto();
    projeto.Titulo = tbxTitulo.Text;
    projeto.TipoDeProjeto = tbxTipo.Text;
    projeto.Plataforma = PlataformaService.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(ddlPlataforma.SelectedValue));
    projeto.Descricao = tbxResumo.Text;
    projeto.SituacaoProjeto = SituacaoProjetoService.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(ddlSituacao.SelectedValue));
    projeto.DataInicio = tbxDataInicio.Text.ToNullableDateTime();
    projeto.Usuario = UsuarioService.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(ddlResponsavel.SelectedValue));
    projeto.Usuario2 = usuarioLogado;
    projeto.UltimaAtualizacao = DateTime.Now;
    projeto.Usuario1 = usuarioLogado;
    projeto.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;

    ProjetoService.Insert(projeto);
    ProjetoService.Save();
```

And this is my auto-generated class

```
    public partial class Projeto
    {
        public Projeto()
        {
            this.AnexoProjeto = new HashSet<AnexoProjeto>();
            this.FinanceiroProjeto = new HashSet<FinanceiroProjeto>();
            this.TarefaProjeto = new HashSet<TarefaProjeto>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public string TipoDeProjeto { get; set; }
        public int IdPlataforma { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public int IdSituacaoProjeto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataInicio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataTermino { get; set; }
        public int IdResponsavel { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime UltimaAtualizacao { get; set; }
        public int IdUsuarioAtualizacao { get; set; }
        public int Prioridade { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
        public int IdUsuarioCriacao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AnexoProjeto> AnexoProjeto { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FinanceiroProjeto> FinanceiroProjeto { get; set; }
        public virtual Plataforma Plataforma { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
        public virtual SituacaoProjeto SituacaoProjeto { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TarefaProjeto> TarefaProjeto { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario2 { get; set; }
    }
```

If i can solve this problem without editing the auto-generated code will be nice. But i need solve anyway.

Comment: Whats the difference between "UsuarioService" and "ProjetoService" are they using the same context?

Comment: try to detach your object _entity.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myObj, EntityState.Detached);

Comment: probably don't need to tag this question asp.net.

Comment: Agreed Adam! Ty for the advice

Comment: What are UsuarioService and PlataformaService? Do you dispose DbContext in method GetById? Show the method GetById. It looks like you get entities from different contextes.

Comment: UsuarioService and PlataformaService are the same as "new UsarioService()" and "new ProjetoService()" with lazyload

Comment: private GenericRepository<TEntity> repository;

public GenericRepository<TEntity> Repository
{
 get
 {
  if (this.repository == null)
  {
   this.repository = new GenericRepository<TEntity>(this.context);
  }
  return repository;
 }
}
public TEntity GetById(int id)
{
 return Repository.GetByID(id);
}